# Maria DB INDEX selection - Why maria is choosing a suboptimal index?

Tags: performance, optimization, indexing, mariadb

I have a quite big table (millions of rows), running on MariaDB (InnoDB, 5.5.48-MariaDB-1~precise-wsrep), let's say my table structure is the following

```
[
ID,
Field A,
Field B,
Field C,
Field D
]
```

I have 3 indexes on this table:

```
- PRIMARY[ID]
- INDEX 1 -> [A,B,C]
- INDEX 2 -> [A, D]
```

The query I am trying to optimize is the following

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (a = val1) AND (B NOT IN ([val2, val3])) AND (C BETWEEN val4 AND val5)
ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100
```

This query should be naturally fitting with my INDEX 1 right? But Maria prefers using the PRIMARY INDEX, which basically means a full table scan (resulting in 40s queries...).

When I remove from this query the ORDER or the LIMIT (or both), Maria DB is able to choose the INDEX 2 which is obviously better than the PRIMARY.

**Question 1 -> Why Maria does fallback to the PRIMARY INDEX when there is a combination of ORDER BY and LIMIT ?**

I decided to tune my query a bit by forbidding the usage of the PRIMARY.

```
SELECT * FROM table IGNORE INDEX(`PRIMARY`)
WHERE (a = val1) AND (B NOT IN ([val2, val3])) AND (C BETWEEN val4 AND val5)
ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100
```

The result -> Quite happy about my first optimization, this 40s query is now taking 1s, but still...

**Question 2 -> why MariaDB is choosing INDEX 2 ?**

When I force Maria to use the INDEX 1 the query drops to 100ms delay (10x faster), for this reason, I am not fully satisfied yet...

Thanks for your help folks :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I DON'T want to force the index selection to INDEX 1, this query might be using different WHERE criteria where INDEX 2 will be the best INDEX, we should still let MariaDB figuring what's the best index.

Comment: Yes the more modern MySQL optimizers tends to use the `ORDER BY` column as index (if possible) to prevent to use a "using temporary using filesort" combination..This combination is lethal for MySQLperformance if allot off records needs to be processed.. if MySQL would need to make a disk based temporary table (which is possible with "using temporary") and do quicksort ("using filesort" (bad name because it's not always on disk it's just quicksort)) on disk it would be really slow. @EtienneCha

Comment: .. The best way to optimize this is by making a [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) which most modern database servers support but MySQL and MariaDB does not still waiting on that feature myself because materialized views are a 2003/2006+ SQL standard i believe .. You would need to simulate that with [Flexviews](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flexviews/) or you can [simulate](https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) that with a table and triggers/event

Comment: .. forgot to mention the materialized view  method also works great when you need `ORDER BY` to work across table columns which you normally can't index in MySQL and would always need to use a "using temporary" or "using temporary using filesort" in worst case.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer @RaymondNijland! Not sure to understand well what you said about filesort -> Do you mean that I should not be doing `IGNORE INDEX(`PRIMARY`)` because it might have some serious performance issue in the future (with more rows to be sorted and so on). BTW the time complexity seems to be very reduced with this modification, but I didn't check the space complexity (memory consumption of Maria) do you think I should check the impact? For the views, I am going to explore this path as well for sure, thanks for your help!

Comment: *"Do you mean that I should not be doing IGNORE INDEX(PRIMARY)"* i didn't meant that, but anny SQL optimizer should do the job beter 99% better out off the cases then you when picking the index or choose to ignore the index

Answer (score 1):

It is the `B NOT IN (val2, vl3)` part that cannot use the index, or not as efficiently as you think it might. I would suggest that you create this index:

```
(A, C, B)
```

Comment: I am going to explore this solution! My first try was not successful (keep using weird index not fitting the query), but my key B having a low cardinality might not be the best at this position. Will let you know how it goes, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about Maria, my guess would be that your limit to the first 50 by ID is the reason.
If Index 1 would be used, there is no way for the system to know *which* 50 IDs will be the lowest, so it has to read *all* matches for your query (*you* know that this would be still faster, but the optimizer can't know that), then read all their IDs, then sort and take the first 50, and drop the rest.
'The rest' here could be 500 million records - the optimizer can't know beforehand; so it decides to go by ID, and accumulate matches until it gets your first 50.

I'd assume if you remove the limit to 50 (or the ORDER BY ID), it would happily use the Index 1.

Another option is to include the ID in the Index 1, maybe at the end even; that would allow the system to do the sort and filter with the result from the index, so it would look favorable to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try to add the ID to the last component of the INDEX 1, without any difference for question 1 (PRIMARY INDEX used when not forbidden).
For question 2, the request with or without the ORDER_BY/LIMIT goes to INDEX 2 without any distinction...